# Sending a cURL terminal command to php $_POST returns null

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, post, curl

So i am relatively new to writing php started learning it last week. this has been giving me problems on the regular since I started writing it. The SQL query populates fine with constant variables but my app is attempting to retrieve users by proximity to them based on their lat and lng values it posts to the webserver. since migrating to the new server $_POST has been giving me a lot of issues. all my scripts worked ok to some respect this one was always a problem but now all my $_POST calls return null values. any and all help is much appreciated? the details below show all the info i know. my webhost is fastwebhost.com if anyone has experience with them and knows if they have settings i dont know about i would be very interested to know more about it.

I am running php 5.5. the curl command is:

```
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"lat":121.1234, "lng":141.1234}' http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php
```

returns the following:

```
nullYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(lat)*pi()/180)
          *POWER(SIN((-lng)*pi()/180/2),2))) '
`
```

the code i am using in my php script is like so:

```
<?php 
//connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
//select db
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($con, "datbasename") or die ("cant find table");

$tableName = "users";
$origLat = $_POST['lat'];
$origLon = $_POST['lng'];
echo json_encode($origLon); //is returning null everytime
$dist = 20; // This is the maximum distance (in miles) away from $origLat, $origLon in which to search


$query = "SELECT username, profile, image_url, lat, lng, 3956 * 2 * 
          ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat - abs(lat))*pi()/180/2),2)
          +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(lat)*pi()/180)
          *POWER(SIN(($origLon-lng)*pi()/180/2),2))) 
          as distance FROM $tableName WHERE 
          lng between ($origLon-$dist/abs(cos(radians($origLat))*69)) 
          and ($origLon+$dist/abs(cos(radians($origLat))*69)) 
          and lat between ($origLat-($dist/69)) 
          and ($origLat+($dist/69)) 
          having distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 100;";

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, $query)  or die(mysqli_error($con));;
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $username, $profile, $image_url ,$lat, $lng, $distance);


  $rows = array();
  while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
     $row = array();
     $row[username] = $username;
     $row[profile] = $profile;
     $row[image_url] = $image_url;
     $row[distance] = $distance;
     array_push($rows, $row);
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con)
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a POST request will have a key/value structure for the POST body, which is what your code `$_POST['lat']` is expecting, with `'lat'` as the key and whatever it is set to as the body. When you send json as the body, it doesn't automatically convert the key/value structure inside the json to a normal `$_POST` global, so you have to do it yourself.

Try code like this to get the json value out of the post body.

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_post = json_decode($post, true);
echo $json_post['lat'] . "\n";
echo $json_post['lng'] . "\n";
```

Comment: this worked thank you! not sure why what i was doing before stopped working but this should solve my problem from here on out hopfully